# save php spreadsheet template as PDF using Mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

i need some help with phpspreadsheet, i'm trying to load an excel spreadsheet, add something to it and then save it as a pdf, the problem is that when i   load a template , saving as pdf doesn't work

ps : when i create a new spreadsheet it works fine.

```
 $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');

 $spreadsheet = $reader->load('docs/MODEL_FACTURE_DOM_CRE.xlsx'); 
 $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B13', 'test')
        ->setCellValue('F13', 'test');                            
 $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false);

 $rendererName = Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;

 Settings::setPdfRendererName($rendererName);

 $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Pdf');

 $filename = 'FACTURE.pdf';

 $writer->save($filename);
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: anyone ????????

Comment: Without knowing anything about your template, or its content, or any error messages that you might be getting, we can't help

Answer (score 0):

Try the older version. On `MPDF` version `v5.7.4a`, your code is work.
In more recent versions there are incompatible changes.